# Blu-ray burning application for PC

Tags: desktop-client, archiving, windows-10

Have some dual density blu ray discs that I want to use to archive data off my Asus laptop.

After some googling online and reading some reviews settled on 2 or 3 free options
Unfortunately these free options also contained either malware or viruses.

Really need some good feedback. Doesn't have to be free, looking for the best option. Does anyone else recommend Nero? $70 seems extremely steep if all u need is to burn CD's, Bluray discs.

Comment: Can you clarify a little?  You are just looking for a program to write data files to dual density blu ray discs?  Is that all?

Comment: exactly. I don't trust reviews in tech blogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m partial to the Nero product line.  It’s not free, but, worth the money (currently $30 US) considering the product offerings.  In your case, I’d suggest taking a look at the [Nero Burning Rom 2016](http://www.nero.com/ena/products/nero-burning-rom/).  While I’ve not used it to burn Blu-ray discs, I’ve used it to burn lots of DVDs and to make copies of data.  The software also provides the ability to protect your disc via an electronic signature and/or password protection.  The interface is pretty simple to use and their support is pretty responsive.  They also provide a user forum for searching and posting questions.  Best of all, they provide a downloaded trial version.

Comment: actually the UPGRADE price is $30. Is it really worth $70???

Comment: Yes.  I think it's worth it.  But, with a free trial, you can check it out first before buying.

Comment: Another [Nero 2016 Platinum Review](http://www.raritysoft.com/reviews/nero-2016-platinum-review) that can help to make a decision